# OPC-UA: recv(buffersize) function gets stuck without any error/warning message

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, opc-ua

**Some information about my relevant-to-the-thread background:**

- Client-Server connection domain knowledge: Beginner
- Python-programmer: Mid to advanced level

**Problem I am facing:**

connecting a Client to a Server using the OPCUA protocol (tool I am using: opcua python-library and VS-code editor).

**How did the problem start?**

- I was attempting to use the `node.get_value()` method (where `node = client.get_node("ns=2;i=2")`). Then the error is: "None type does not have a method called 'send_request'". This made me think that the socket connection is not established. Therefore, I tried to establish a socket connection first, by using the `UAClient.connect_socket()` method, which lead me to the origin of the problem, which is the last command line in the following code:

**My code:**

```
from opcua import Server
from opcua import Client
from opcua import ua
from ua_client import *
from traceback import print_exc
from opcua import Client



name = "OPC_SIMULATION_SERVER" 
addspace = server.register_namespace(name)
node = server.get_objects_node()
Param = node.add_object(addspace, "Parameters")

server = Server() 
url = 'opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:4840' # opc server URL (connection works, checked in in command line with "ping")

server.start()
print("Server started at {}".format(url))

client = Client(url) # create client object
ref = client.uaclient # create UAClient object
# establish socket (to my understanding)
ref._uasocket = UASocketClient(ref._timeout, security_policy=ref.security_policy)
host = client.server_url.hostname
port = client.server_url.port
refsock = ref._uasocket
sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout=refsock.timeout)
sock.settimeout(None) # for blocking (doesn’t cause the error)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
refsock._socket = ua.utils.SocketWrapper(sock)

# ERRATIC LINE: The following command gets stuck without an error/warning message
chunk = refsock._socket.socket.recv(8)
# \==================================================
```

I should note that initially I had no problem with getting the value from the node.

Comment: '"None type does not have a method called 'send_request'". This made me think that the socket connection is not established.' Well it shouldn't have. It should have told you that you have a *compilation error* in your code. You're barking up the wrong tree altogether.

Comment: I'm at the right tree alright. Like I mention in the thread, I attempted to create socket connection and receive data (last line of my code block), which indeed does not work. And one can't see that error if one runs the code externally, i.e. without going through the code lines. And since the connection cannot be established, I get a "NoneType" for socket connection